# Arduino communication via COM Port isnt working

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino-uno

I want my Arduino to light up the LED if he reads "on" in the Serial Port.
At `Serial.print(serialData);` it prints out what he reads but at `if (serialData == "on")` it wont work.

```
int led1 = 9;
int led2 = 6;
String serialData;
void setup() {      
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    serialData = Serial.readString();
    Serial.print(serialData);
    if (serialData == "on"){
      analogWrite(led1, 255);
    }
    if (serialData == "off"){
      analogWrite(led1, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody know, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- The timeout is set to 10ms. In 10ms, you can at best enter a single character. `readString()` will return after a single character and the read string will likely be "o", "n", "f".
- When you hit the RETURN key, a carriage return and a line feed character are also transmitted ("\r\n").

The solution is to increase the timeout considerably and to use `readStringUntil()` to read until the newline character is discovered. This is the indication that a full word (or command) has been entered.

Additionally, the carriage return and line feed need to be trimmed off.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int led1 = 9;
int led2 = 6;
String serialData;

void setup() {      
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    serialData = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    serialData.trim();
    Serial.println(serialData);
    if (serialData == "on"){
      analogWrite(led1, 255);
    }
    if (serialData == "off"){
      analogWrite(led1, 0);
    }
  }
}
```